# Nextjs graphql mutation stuck send request

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

This is my code to delete a user:

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string | null>(null);


  const DELETE_USER = gql`
    mutation RemoveUser($_id: String!) {
      removeUser(_id: $_id)
    }
  `;
  const [removeUser, { loading, error }] = useMutation(DELETE_USER);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        _id: selected,
      },
    });
  };


...

 <Button isLoading={loading} onClick={handleDelete} variant="ghost">
              Delete
            </Button>
```

**Note**: **selected** is always non empty before the **handleDelete** function call.

I don't get any error or warning and I am just stuck in the loading state in the UI.

Comment: Try to check DevConsole, 'Network' section to see what is the status of your request

Comment: @DavidYappeter No request sent

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the `handleDelete` function? You might want to update your snippet to show how you're calling it.

Comment: @hwillson snippet updated

Answer (score 2):

env variable was undefined on the client-side in nextjs. the problem is solved.